# Where do you see your Meta flags?

Tags: discussion, flags, flag-history

On SO there is a link to your own helpful flags in your profile. I don't see that link on Meta. Where do I see a list of flags that I have submitted on Meta?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The link is in the same place; here's my user profile on Meta.SO:

[image]

But, you won't see it if you haven't flagged anything or if none of your flags have been handled.  Here's my profile on another meta site, where I haven't raised any flags:

[image]

You should see it as soon as any flag is handled, even if it is declined. Here's my profile on a beta site where my flag history consists only of 2 declined flags:

[image]

Comment: That's it - I only have active flags, nothing useful or helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It's in the same place - at least for me. Not sure why it doesn't show up on your profile; perhaps you don't have any flags marked as useful yet.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1011527 - This normally would be the link for your flag summary. Currently it's a 404.

Comment: Your meta.SO flag summary page is a 404 for me as well. The page is probably private.

Comment: @Air Yes, of course it is private. Do you want someone to browse your flag history?